# Some system Apps lost after hard reset

Tags: 8.0, update

I just reseted my Lumia 820. Now some system apps like glance are missing.

Info says I have Nokia enhancements 1.x.
the update service does not find any updates. Before there was Amber installed.

the phone has a Denmark code, and the language and locale is set to German.

thanks

edit: I forgot to mention, that there were like 19 apps in the store as downloads. They all failed, since the name of them was Application XY, I thought that this were apps removed from the store.

is there any way to redo a update to the newest version?

Comment: Did you tried Lumia Pusher?

Comment: @NK this seems a way to get the apps back. Thank you. But some apps like e.g. extra+info are shown as not avaible for my phone. Would installing the Preview for Developers (GDR3) help?

Comment: May be issue with your carrier or country region. I'm using GDR3, it doesn't have apps like glance and something, but pushed everything with above application pusher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find and install them all with SysApp Pusher.

The app let you find all apps for every brand, included beta ones.

You can find it in the [Windows Phone Store](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/sysapp-pusher/19d44d9e-f18e-4df1-9bce-36335242ed2e).

[image]

Comment: It's a shame that this app isn't available in all locales (or for WP7.x, for that matter) :(

Comment: Didn't know that. My store is set to USA.

Answer (score 2):

You can also log into the [Windows Phone Store](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/my/purchase-history) on a PC and view a list of all of the phone apps you've installed in the past and push them to your phone from the web. This includes apps that came preinstalled on your phone by the manufacturer or by your carrier. I have frequently used this to make sure that all of my apps get properly installed after changing phones or factory resetting a phone. For pushing apps to work, your phone must have "Find my Phone" enabled in the settings.

FYI, when you reset your phone and restore a backup from your Microsoft Account, some apps may fail to install, as you described. This is usually because the app is not fully compatible with Windows Phone 8. I had this trouble with Flashlight XT until the app developer updated the app for Windows Phone 8.